# How do I alter a loader program in C

Tags: c, printing, cpu, loader

[Assignment guidelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIhX4.png)

https://github.com/OliverRyan123/loader -> c file on github

I am trying to understand how to alter this file so that it will allow for N to equal 3, instead of just 2. Hopefully someone can help, or at the very least point me in the right direction?

edit:
I suppose my question is rather vague. The assignment is asking me to alter the current code, so that when a user enters a.out 3 inputfile, that the current output will be different than N = 2. As of now, the code allows for only when N = 2, or rather 8 semaphores, 2 loaders, 2 exec, 2 outputs, and 2 printers. Simply, job0 and job1. I need to change the code so in the printer, cpu, and loader functions, it will do an additional loader, exec, output, and printer, or again job2. So, as the assignment link above displays where N= 3 it will load job0 into memory 0-9, job1 into 10-19, and job2 (what needs to be coded in) into 20-29. Then, it will print job0 at 30-39, job1 at 40-49, and job2 (new) 50-59. I have been able to add in main the command line agruments, so when the user types a.out 2 inputfilename it will initialize 8 semaphores, and when its a.out 3 inputfilename it will initialize 12 semaphores. Although, now I do not know where to go.

The input file is also in github now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  You're asking a very broad question, and not making your question self-contained.  We should not have to visit any external site in order to see the question.  It's OK to add links to backup material, but the main question should be understandable without external references.  There are 400+ lines in the code — that means you need to read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), too.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and try to change something in that `loader.c` file, then debug it. Hint: compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and learn about [Debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). BTW StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework service. You are expected to think, learn and read by yourself.

Comment: Perhaps you could also read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're simply asking how to set a variable from the command line when starting the program. The following should help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Used on error, returns one to simplify error checking blocks.

int Usage(char *reason) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", reason);
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: progName N, where N is 2 or 3.\n");
    return 1;
}

// Main showing how to verify arguments.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Check for program 'name' and one other argument.

    if (argc != 2) return Usage("wrong number of arguments");

    // Get and check that other argument.

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (n < 2 || n > 3) return Usage("N is neither 2 nor 3");

    // n is now 2 or 3, go wild!
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I suppose I am not explaining well enough. I know how to add the command line arguments. I am lost in how to add code to the loader, printer, and cpu function so that when the user enters N = 3, it will display something different than N = 2.

Comment: I attached the input text file in github for review too.